# WP API - How to get draft posts

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am trying to get draft/preview/trash posts using the [wordpress JSON API](http://wp-api.org/) but adding the filter doesn't seem to do anything at all.

As a test, I am trying to get posts in the trash (there are non) but all published posts are returned.

```
http://localhost/wp-json/posts?&filter[post_status]=trash
```

I have tried this whilst logged in and out of the admin panel, giving the same results.

I am assuming this was the way to do it based on the wordpress docs http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

I have attempted multiple params other than trash, all return only published posts.

EDIT:

I figured out that you cannot be logged into the admin panel for basic auth to work, otherwise it just gets overridden. Logging out of this and it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be authenticated as a user with edit_posts permissions to access private query variables such as post_status. At which point you will be able to use the following (drop the &).

http://localhost/wp-json/posts?filter[post_status]=trash

EDIT:

I believe there is a way to add post_status manually, I haven't tested this but it should work.

```
function my_allowed_post_status( $valid_vars ) {

    $valid_vars = array_merge( $valid_vars, array( 'post_status' ) );
    return $valid_vars;
}
add_filter( 'rest_query_vars', 'my_allowed_post_status' );
```